# export Datatable csv to excel scientific number c#

Tags: c#, excel, csv, datatable, export-to-csv

I have a code that exports a datatable to csv that works perfectly, but when I'm going to convert text to columns in Excel, it treats the rows as a scientific number, even though I've escaped the fields before exporting.

Here is the code:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string[] columnNames = DT.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                          ToArray();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

        foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
        {
            string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\"")).ToArray();

            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }

        File.WriteAllText(fileNamecsv, sb.ToString());
```

Anyone have a suggestion for a way that I export the field as text so that when converting text to columns in Excel, the Excel does not convert rows that have number to scientific number?

Thanks

Comment: Is the column wide enough to display the number without resorting to scientific notation?

Comment: When I go in excel and click on the text option for columns and transform, it is not wide enough, but even enlarging it uses the scientific notation.